# Need to print out a message when the DODAG converge

Tags: iot, contiki, cooja

I am new to Contiki/Cooja. Any helps are greatly appreciated. I need to find out the time it takes for a DODAG to form and stabilizes. So my questions are:

1. What code in examples should I use/start with? Currently I am using the ones in ipv6/simple-udp-rpl.
2. I like the root node to print out a message when the DODAG converges, where do I put the code into?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, share your codes

Comment: You can print the number of routes on the root node and check if that number is equal to the total number of non-root nodes in the network. The `simple-udp-rpl` is a good example to start.